# Generating thumbnail from video using php classes

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, video-thumbnails

I was using the exec command to generate thumbnails via ffmpeg..
My method was:

```
exec("ffmpeg -f image2 -i /home/phedra/imgs/image/img%03d.png -r 12 -s 610x489 /home/phedra/imgs/video/out.avi", $out);
```

but my senior team member told me that using exec command is not a good practice because it is a dangerous command and It may harm server.. So find any other technique.. I struggled alot but didnt find any comprehensive method other than this..
Can anybody tell me anyother way to generate thumbnail from video using php class from scratch (With an example if possible), so that I could understand completely, Moreover also tell me the library link to download and settings for server if any setting needed to be done before using that technque(My server system is based on Ubuntu and the framework for developement is codeignitter)..

(Third party api tool for generating thumbnail is also welcome but the necessary thing is that it must be free:))

Comment: Unrelated: By default `ffmpeg` will use a frame rate of 25 for image inputs. You applied `-r 12` as an output option, so in your case `ffmpeg` will drop frames to reach your desired output frame rate. You can move `-r 12` to be an input option (before `-i`) and the output will also use the frame rate, or have separate `-r` for input and output.

Comment: You are right sir. I'm not using the same string in exec command.. It is just an example of method that I was using to generate thumbnails. My real code is working fine in my scenario, but my senior team member has told me to not to use exec command.. I want to know any other simple method to generate thumbnails without using exec command.